# How to add new key value pair to an object in an array based on another key-value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 JSON objects:

```
obj1 = [{
    "screenCode": "usr_ooo_master",
    "screenName": "Out Of Office Master"
    }, {
    "screenCode": "usr_user_master",
    "screenName": "User Master"
    }]

obj2 = [{
    "id": "10a310a8-6f01-4082-af86-bb73019cff8d",
    "cascadeImpact": {
        "screenCode": "usr_user_master",
        "impactedModuleCode": "borrower2"
    },
    "screenImpactedCode": "bor_address1"
}, {
    "id": "308c8058-5e98-4b99-a1c6-82e9e5c93787",
    "cascadeImpact": {
        "screenCode": "usr_ooo_master",
        "impactedModuleCode": "borrower2"
    },
    "screenImpactedCode": "bor_address2"
}]
```

I want to add a new key-value pair to obj2 depending on the "screenCode". So eg. I want to add "screenName": "User Master" to obj2 first element. How do I do that.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/")

Comment: [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) + [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Where do you want to add the `"screenName": "User Master"`? First element of the `obj2` or inside the `cascadeImpact` of the first element?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the corresponding key/values pairs to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and update the object with the result of the `map`.

```js
var array1 = [{ screenCode: "usr_ooo_master", screenName: "Out Of Office Master" }, { screenCode: "usr_user_master", screenName: "User Master" }],
    array2 = [{ id: "10a310a8-6f01-4082-af86-bb73019cff8d", cascadeImpact: { screenCode: "usr_user_master", impactedModuleCode: "borrower2" }, screenImpactedCode: "bor_address1" }, { id: "308c8058-5e98-4b99-a1c6-82e9e5c93787", cascadeImpact: { screenCode: "usr_ooo_master", impactedModuleCode: "borrower2" }, screenImpactedCode: "bor_address2" }],
    map = new Map(array1.map(({ screenCode, screenName }) => [screenCode, screenName]));

array2.forEach(({ cascadeImpact }) =>
    cascadeImpact.screenName = map.get(cascadeImpact.screenCode));

console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj2['screenName'] = 'User Master'
```

The only thing I a little but doubt is within obj2 you have single-element array. If the above won't work, you can always iterate on obj2 like (JQuery version):

```
$.each(obj2, function(index, element) {
   element['screenName'] = 'User Master';
}
```

Having in mind you olny have 1 element in the array - it will iterate only once (but the resource hunger will be larger than if you just do the assignment like in the first code)

Answer (score 0):

if u want to add key to specific item just use key of that item: obj2[0]['screenName'] = "test" otherwise there is loop down below:

```js
obj2 = [{
    "id": "10a310a8-6f01-4082-af86-bb73019cff8d",
    "cascadeImpact": {
        "screenCode": "usr_user_master",
        "impactedModuleCode": "borrower2"
    },
    "screenImpactedCode": "bor_address1"
}, {
    "id": "308c8058-5e98-4b99-a1c6-82e9e5c93787",
    "cascadeImpact": {
        "screenCode": "usr_ooo_master",
        "impactedModuleCode": "borrower2"
    },
    "screenImpactedCode": "bor_address2"
}]

for(var i=0;i < obj2.length; i++){
   obj2[i]['screenName'] = 'Master-' + (i+1);
   obj2[i]['screenCode'] = 'Code-' + (i+1);
}

console.log(obj2)
```